# distinguish between hard drives in Windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installation

Usually I distinguish between two hard-drives in Windows installations by their size, however this time I have two equal-sized hard drives, how can I know exactly which one is which during Windows 7 installation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a dummy partition in one of them, so you can see it in the installation to recognize the disk.

Comment: Nice one... But I hoped theres a magic key combination that shows the serial num of thr disc...

Comment: Another option: Unplug the secondary disk, install W7 and then plug again.